# Compare a list and a tuple containing numpy arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I have a python list which contains numpy arrays like:

```
a = [Numpy array 1, Numpy array 2, Numpy array 3]
```

These Numpy arrays are all 2D numpy arrays.

Now if i pick any two Numpy arrays from my list 'a' randomly and make a tuple, say,

```
b = (Numpy array 1, Numpy array 2)
```

How can i detect which arrays were picked i.e.

`Numpy array 1, Numpy array 2`

and which weren't i.e

`Numpy array 3`?

Let me repharse my question: 
**Which numpy array from my list 'a' is not present in the tuple 'b'?**

Comment: Why are you using a list? Do the arrays have different shape?

Comment: You could perhaps store the numpy arrays within a dict? That way you can assign a key to the array and maybe give away with the tuple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by converting the `numpy` array to a list.
Let's imagine this is your `a` and `b`:

```
import random
a = [np.arange(10).reshape(2,5), np.arange(10,20), np.arange(20,30)] # list of numpy arrays
first = random.randint(0,2)
second = first
while second==first:
    second = random.randint(0,2)
b = (a[first],a[second])
```

Now we want to know which element of `a` is not in the tuple `b`. You first convert the numpy arrays of `b` to list. Then you can check it with the elements of `a` which are also converted to list:

```
def arrayinList(arr, listOfArray):
    return next((True for elem in listOfArray if np.array_equal(elem, arr)), False)

missing_elem = [elem for elem in a if not arrayinList(elem,b) ]
print(missing_elem)
```

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
this error is being thrown by this line:
`missing_elem = [elem for elem in i if list(elem) not in list_b]`

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal what is `i` in your code? And have you defined `list_b` as the above code? The code I have written is tested dozen of times and runs without any error. I guess that you have not defined `list_b` as the above code. First copy the code in my answer and run it. It should run correctly. After that check what you have programmed differently.

Comment: Your code is working fine. And i am editing your code exactly as above i.e Replacing your a and b accordingly to my a and b. But error still exists. I think the problem is 2D arrays? My numpy arrays are 2D arrays. While your arrays are 1D.

Comment: @AbdullahAjmal You are correct. I was assuming that your arrays are one dimensional. I have changed the code to also work for a list of arrays with different dimensions.

Comment: yeah it works now. That's exactly what i wanted. thank you so much.